# Can I create a calendar trigger with service account and impersonation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

I implemented a Google Calendar AddOn which connects to a 3rd party service when an event is created. In order to get updates when the event is changed in any way I create a [installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for the event creator which works fine.

However when someone else creates an event in the name of another person using [delegation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) this does not work since the Calendar Trigger only fires for your default calendar apparently.

And there is also no API to create a Trigger so that I could user a service account and impersonate "the other person" to setup a Trigger there.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior? An API to create a trigger would solve the problem since I can use a service account and create it but if there is none? Maybe some clever workaround?

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately there is no API or URLs to which you could send requests for creating Apps Script triggers

The API with which you can control (to some degree) Apps-Script code is the [Apps-Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts?authuser=1), but as you can see under [Limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute?authuser=1#limitations):

> The API cannot create Apps Script triggers.

Comment: so in other words: you can not create a trigger for another user via API

Comment: To my best knowledge - this is not possible.